# Python Write to file with variable names, but it doesn't seem to work well

Tags: python, file

In response to the previous question, I am now trying to do something different. I am trying to write the user's name and their score to a text file that I called, just for testing purposes (newfile.txt):

This is the code so far:

```
file = open("newfile.txt", "w")

user_name = str(input("What is your name?"))
user_score = int(input("What score did you get?"))

file.write(user_name, ":", user_score "\n")
```

I am trying to write the name and the score in the form name:score, so for instance since my name is Taylor and if I got a score of 10, I would expect the file to show Taylor : 10. 

Why is this not working?

Comment: write takes a single string.  you can add strings together with `+`.  also `user_score` needs to be converted to a string.

Comment: For future reference, your code produces a syntax error. So when you say  your code is "not working" you should post the full traceback with the error so people know what you are referring to specifically.

Answer (score 2):

`.write()` takes a single argument. You need to create a single string to pass. Instead of

```
file.write(user_name, ":", user_score "\n")
```

You could use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to create your string.

```
file.write('{} : {}\n'.format(user_name, user_score))
```

As a side note, I would recommend using the `with` keyword to handle file opening and closing for you.

```
with open("newfile.txt", "w") as f:
    user_name = str(input("What is your name? "))
    user_score = int(input("What score did you get? "))
    f.write('{} : {}\n'.format(user_name, user_score))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about put the content you want to write to the file in a new var? And `write()` only take a parameter of string type but `user_score` is an int type:

```
file = open("newfile.txt", "w")

user_name = str(input("What is your name?"))
user_score = int(input("What score did you get?"))

content = user_name + ':' + str(user_score) + '\n'

file.write(content)

file.close() # close the file
```

Besides, make sure close the file or it will not close until your program ends.